# strings.Replacer: position dependent bug/functionality?

Tags: go

I get the output:

```
Hello World
Hello
```

With the following code:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main(){
    s := "Hello World"
    fmt.Println(strings.NewReplacer("Hello","").Replace(s))
    fmt.Println(strings.NewReplacer("World","").Replace(s))
}
```

Is this a bug? Is there a better way to remove substrings?

Comment: It seems that the implementation is trying to handle single-replacement as a special case - is the bug there? If I instead add a second replacement to the arg lists "l","" the output appears correct (output becomes ' Word
Heo ')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no go expert, but it looks like a bug to me.

This works:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main(){
    s := "Hello World"
    fmt.Println(strings.NewReplacer("Hello"," ").Replace(s))
    fmt.Println(strings.NewReplacer("World","").Replace(s))
}
```

Output:

```
   World 

Hello
```

Maybe there is an empty string keyword?

Even this works:

```
fmt.Println(strings.NewReplacer("ello", "").Replace(s))
```

This also works:

```
fmt.Println(strings.NewReplacer("Hello","", "Hi", "").Replace(s))
```

As orthopteroid mentioned, it seems single-replacement is special cased and buggy.

Comment: Thanks for checking the "ello" case. I've opened a bug http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6660

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug. It is now fixed in tip.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/CNdpwbCSbHM

And here is another way to remove substrings:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Replace("Hello World", "Hello", "", 1))
}
```